# Magento 2 | Access custom order attribute

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes

I created an custom attribute for orders:

> UpgradeSchema.php

```
<?php



use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * Upgrades DB schema for a module
     *
     * @param SchemaSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $quote = 'quote';
        $orderTable = 'sales_order';

        $setup->getConnection()
            ->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable($quote),
                'mediabasebestellnummer',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'comment' =>'MediabaseNummer'
                ]
            );
        //Order table
        $setup->getConnection()
            ->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable($orderTable),
                'mediabasebestellnummer',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'comment' =>'MediabaseNummer'
                ]
            );

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Right now my question is how get the custom attribute when I have an order.
This is NOT working:

```
$custom = $order->getCustomAttribute('mediabasebestellnummer');
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you try $custom = $order->getMediabasebestellnummer();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check if the column is created in `sales_order` table

Now getting the values

```
 $order->getMediabasebestellnummer();
```

Or

```
$order->getData('mediabasebestellnummer');
```

For adding the data

```
 $order->setMediabasebestellnummer('test value')->save();
```

or

```
 $order->setData('mediabasebestellnummer','test value')->save();
```

or

```
$data = array('mediabasebestellnummer'=>'test');
$order->setData($data)->save();`
```

Comment: is there also a possibility to Set?

Comment: @L.Klmn `set` is use to assign the value not for fetching.

Comment: yes I also need that. :)

Comment: @L.Klmn added the possible solutions ..

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have file `fieldset.xml` in your module to convert data from quote to order.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:DataObject/etc/fieldset.xsd">
    <scope id="global">
        <fieldset id="sales_convert_quote">
            <field name="mediabasebestellnummer">
                <aspect name="to_order" />
            </field>
        </fieldset>
    </scope>
</config>
```

Comment: where should I place that?

Comment: @L.Klmn it is used when you have column in both `quote` and   `order`  table.

Comment: @L.Klmn You could place that in *etc* folder, and  yes, if you have column in both table, it will convert from quote table to sales_order table